# How to zoom in and out with Moviepy

Tags: python, zooming, moviepy

I have a video in 1080P resolution and need to perform various editing tasks, including rotation, cropping, trimming, and zooming. While I've successfully applied all these edits using MoviePy, I'm encountering an issue with the zoom effect.

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to zoom in and out by a specified factor without altering the video's resolution. I attempted to use the 'resize' function in MoviePy, but it didn't seem to have any effect, and I'm unsure if it's equivalent to achieving the zoom effect I want. My goal is to maintain the video's original resolution throughout.

Although this may seem like a straightforward task, I haven't been able to find a clear function in MoviePy that accomplishes this.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to achieve the zoom effect with MoviePy. If MoviePy doesn't offer a straightforward solution, I'd also like to know if there are other libraries that provide this functionality out of the box. While I'm aware of the option to implement it with OpenCV, I'm hoping to explore alternatives.

Comment: Please share a [mre] of your own code that's in question.

Comment: There's not much to reproduce.

 zoom = vid.resize(1.75)

Comment: More context would be helpful though. We should be able to paste your code into an IDE and see the issue ourselves, ideally.